# From VBA code works, to no changes in the code and suddenly code doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to sort two columns

```
Sub SortMultipleColumns()

Sheet1.Activate


With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Q10"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("R10"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range("Q10:R9999")
     .Header = xlNo
     .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Column Q is integers, Column R is strings.

The sorting was working just fine, then 5 minutes later I didn't change anything and know I get the following error : "Run time error 1004" Application defined or object defined error. According to the debugger the bug shows up after .Apply

Comment: You can use simpler [Range.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) method, if you use up to 3 fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding .SortFields.Clear before adding keys. Else it will try to again add same keys and might be the cause of your error

```
With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Clear
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Q10"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("R10"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range("Q10:R9999")
     .Header = xlNo
     .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Thank you it seemed to work with this as well With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("Q10:R" & .Range("R10").End(xlDown).Row).Sort _
    Key1:=Range("R10"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End With